# How can I efficiently remove duplicates from a large list in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates

I need to remove every duplicate item from a list of more than 100 million things. I tried converting the list to a set and back again using the Set method, but it is far too sluggish and slow and memory-intensive. Are there any other effective solutions to achieve this?

Comment: you are probably not going to find a *faster* method.

Comment: 100M+ _"things"_, how many GB is that? Do you have enough RAM? I mean swapping may slow everything down and if it happens to be the case, that should be probably addressed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to sort your list, then this is fairly trivial.  Sort it first, then take the unique items.  This is the same approach as `sort | uniq` in shell, and can be quite memory efficient (using disk instead, of course, Python's built-in sort will be in-memory).

[Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

```
def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBcCAD', str.lower) --> A B c A D
    return map(next, map(operator.itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

Is there a reason you care if this is sluggish?  If you need to do this operation often then something is wrong in the way you are handling data.

Comment: Ugh, itertools soup. It's easier to read like this: `for _k, g in groupby(iterable, key): yield next(g)`

Comment: sorting is almost certainly less efficient than using a set

Comment: @mozway I suppose since sets involve *O(n)* space in addition to *O(n)* time, memory access could be OP's bottleneck. Meanwhile sorting is constant space and *O(n log n)* time, ofc.

Comment: @wjandrea sorting is O(N) space in Python

Comment: This will *not* be space efficient in Python, since it isn't using an external (on disk) sorting algorithm. It will require O(N) space, although, potentially with a small constant factor. But it's worth a shot

Comment: @wjandrea yeah, timsort requires auxiliary space (although it may not,  but that is a best-case scenario). Just because the object itself is modified doesn't mean that extra space isn't used underneath the hood. If you use a key function, it will *always* use an entirely new list underneath the hood (since it basically does `aux = list(map(keyfunc, inputlist))`. Anyway, it may in fact use a lot less space than converting to a `set` so it's worth a shot

Comment: @juanpa Oh, huh, I didn't realize that. I think I was thinking of a different sorting algo, sorry, so I deleted my comment as soon as I started reading about Timsort.